# Good tools for analyzing VPS performance (VPS running WordPress blogs)?

Tags: wordpress, vps

What are tools you would recommend for analyzing VPS performance?  Specifically I run several Wordpress blogs on a VPS and would like to find some tools to help me find issues worth looking into (so I can address them).

I use New Relic for getting some data on where to focus some attention on our Rails applications and find it very useful.

I have a feeling there might be issues with memory use.  I would love to see something that showed memory use over time so I could see what my memory use looks like.  I am considering upgrading the VPS and this would be one useful piece of data.

Answer (score 2):

"top" is always a good place to start in the terminal.

but http://scoutapp.com/ is a really good monitoring app, and easy to implement on vps servers

Answer (score 2):

Try Munin, is a great monitoring app with a web interface, http://munin-monitoring.org/

Answer (score 1):

cloudstats.me
works free for three VPS

Comment: And you can monitor up to 50 blogs here : uptimerobot.com

Answer (score 0):

[New Relic has a free server monitoring service](http://newrelic.com/docs/server/new-relic-for-server-monitoring) that will show you CPU, memory, network I/O,  disk I/O, and disk capacity, as well as a process list a la `top`.

Comment: Actually I did start using New Relic for this about a year ago. awhile back. The free service is extremely limited.  I want to see use over time and free New Relic doesn't do this.  Munin is by far the best option I have found.  I used the New Relic paid version at work for years and it is great (but expensive).